# Effect of robust maximum likelihood estimator in structural equation modelling when data is normal?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, robust, lavaan, growth-model

I understand that when data are nonnormal robust maximum likelihood estimator can be used.

**I'm wondering are there any disadvantages of using a robust maximum likelihood estimator when the data *are* normally distributed?**

The reason I ask is that I am running latent growth curve models separately for four cognitive outcomes. Three out of four cognitive outcomes violate the assumption of normality, however one does not. I'm wondering whether it is best to use a robust estimator for all four variables. I have run the analyses with and without the robust estimator and it does not seem to change my conclusions regarding model fit of linear vs. quadratic models for example, but wonder if I am missing something.

Specifically, I plan to use the "MLR" estimator in lavaan (R): maximum likelihood estimation with robust (Huber-White) standard errors and a scaled test statistic that is (asymptotically) equal to the Yuan-Bentler test statistic. For both complete and incomplete data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are there any disadvantages of using a robust maximum likelihood estimator when the data are normally distributed?

- Loss of efficiency. The normality assumption is what makes ML point estimates efficient (smallest sampling distribution). Using a robust estimator to avoid that assumption generally increases *SE* estimates, although sampling error still applies (so in specific samples, for specific estimates, the *SE* could be smaller or larger between (non)robust solutions). This is the same issue in robust regression solutions (e.g., heteroskedasticity-consistent covariance matrices).
- Inflated Type I error rates. The unwanted effects of a violated normality assumption are due to fourth-order moments (excessive kurtosis).  Estimating a population's fourth-order moments from sample data requires even larger samples than the covariance matrix (second-order moments) for stability.  So if your sample size is not large, robust/scaled test stats can have inflated Type I error rates, whether normality is violated or not.

Comment: Thank you! Would a sample size of 850 be large enough to overcome some of these issues? If you have any references you could share on this topic - that would be great!

Comment: It depends on how many variables you are modeling, as well as the reliability of indicators.  You can search Google Scholar for articles about "structural equation modeling robust maximum likelihood simulation" to search related literature.